# Htaccess condition question

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello i want make an condition in htaccess

if link is contain category

rewrite [test.txt] to [/category/test.txt]

i trying

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(category)/$
RewriteRule ^/category/test.txt$ /test.txt [L]
```

i want tell him if it contain not if it equal !

the rewrite rule working fine without condition

but after adding condition , it does not work !

and link is contain 'category' word !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} category
```

Don't use that ^ if you don't want it - it means it will only match at the beginning of a string. The $ at the end means it will only match at the end of a request uri.

Comment: Finally !!
i am searching for 3 days ago for that fix !
in finally i found it
it's working fine
i don't know what should i tell you !!
but really ! thank you :(